# googlemaps api responds with error message "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Tags: api, google-maps

I just started using googlemaps api.
When I opened the page, it always gives me the same error message,
which says
"Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html".
and nothing can be seen on the page.

I quite don't know how to figure out what is wrong..
I paste my code below. Thank you for your help.

----------my code from here--------------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charaset="utf-8">
<title>Googlemap</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=ja"></script>
<style>
    #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.66, 139.69);
    var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

----------my code until here--------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a relative width and height to the `map` DIV, but you also need to assign either an absolute or relative width and height to the parent elements (i.e, html and body).

Example:

```
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code as sample code and follow it, please also don't forget to download the `default.css` that is mentioned in the same code.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple

go to this link and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to view the source of this page, and then save it with `.html` extension.

It will work.